# Hilbert's foundations of geometry theorem 17

Tags: geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I am reading Hilbert's foundations of geometry, translated by Townsend. The theorem 17 and 18 don't have proofs, probably because they are too obvious, I don't know. And I haven't been able to see why they are correct.

Hilbert puts them down as "most general theorems relating to congruences in a plane".

Here is theorem 17:

> If $( A, B, C, \dots  )$ and $(A_0 , B_0, C_0,  \ldots )$ are congruent plane figures and $P$
>   is a point in the plane of the first, then it is always possible to find a point $P_0$ in
>   the plane of the second figure so that $(A, B, C, \ldots, P) $ and $( A_0 , B_ 0, C_ 0, \ldots, P_0 )$ shall
>   likewise be congruent figures. If the two figures have at least three points not
>   lying in a straight line, then the selection of $P_0$ can be made in only one way.

Could someone explain why three points?

Comment: I recommend some books that do Hilbert's axioms in a more relaxed manner, such as Hartshorne, Geometry:Euclid and Beyond, also Marvin Jay Greenberg, Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry (I'm in the fourth edition). When I was writing my article, I relied on Martin, The Foundations of Geometry and the Non-Euclidean Plane. These books are also not "easy" but are intended for use in the classroom, the audience being students

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the references. My next goal is going to be learning some more about the basis for quantum mechanics equations, that's why I wanted to scan Hilbert's foundations first. Will, for example Hartshorne give the generality I need to continue with next steps?

Comment: A guess: if the two figures don't have at least 3 non-colinear points, we are in the degenerate case of lines...

Comment: Hilbert spaces are something quite different. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Comment: Chris, I couldn't understand what you meant by degenerate case. If it's the same as what I posted, could you post it instead and I'll accept it as answer?

Comment: I have undeleted.

Comment: Be warned that Hilbert's "Foundations of Geometry" have NOTHING TO DO with Hilbert spaces used in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guess:  if the two figures don't have at least 3 non-colinear points,  we are in the degenerate case of lines...

addition:

And in degenerate case, you can have a $P_0$ on both sides of the figure and will have the same figure (for example, you can rotate the plane).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the proof with all details in "Foundations of geometry" by Karol Borsuk and Wanda Szmielew in paragraph 34 of chapter II (starting from page 131).